# How can I use the @Environment(\.calendar) in a View to initialize a @State variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, environment

I have a calendar view like so:

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) var calendar
    @State var daysForMonthView: [DateInterval]
    ...
}
```

where i need to initialize the `daysForMonthView` array by using the `@Environment(\.calendar)`. How can I do that?

Trying to do:

```
init() {
    _daysForMonthView = State(initialValue: calendar.daysForMonthViewContaining(date: Date()))
}
```

produces a `Variable 'self.daysForMonthView' used before being initialized` -error.

Comment: Why not in use an `init()`?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: To be able to set `daysForMonthView` in `init()`, I will have to first assign an empty array in the variable declaration like this `@State var daysForMonthView: [DateInterval] = []`. The problem is that `body` will be executed with that empty array, while the new value assigned in `init` never takes effect.

Comment: What you want to achieve is just impossible. You can't use `self` until you initialise all the properties. Which means you can't use `self` to initialise another property. That's just how Swift works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign all the properties before you can access the `@Environment`. For this reason you can't use `calendar` to initialise `daysForMonthView`.

A possible solution is to use `onAppear`:

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) private var calendar
    @State private var daysForMonthView: [DateInterval] = [] // assign empty
    
    var body: some View {
        //...
        .onAppear {
            daysForMonthView = calendar...
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you need `calendar` to be available in the `init`, you can pass it as a parameter in `init`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.calendar) private var calendar

    var body: some View {
        CalendarView(calendar: calendar)
    }
}

struct CalendarView: View {
    private let calendar: Calendar
    @State private var daysForMonthView: [DateInterval]
    
    init(calendar: Calendar) {
        self.calendar = calendar
        self._daysForMonthView = .init(initialValue: calendar...)
    }

    //...
}
```

Note: the downside of this approach is that a change to the `calendar` will reinitialise the whole `CalendarView`.